# Memo in manageoffer

Tags: memo, manageofferoperation

Can a memo be included in the managerOffer operation.
I tried to include a memo in my manageoffer transaction but it did not go thru.

Answer (score 3):

The memo is part of the transaction, it's never part of an operation. You can set a memo in any transaction no matter what kind of operations it contains, so a transaction with a memo and a manageOffer operation should work fine.

You will find the reason for transaction failure in the horizon.submitTransaction calls response. It can be a bit tricky to decode it (server response is json, contains a `result_xdr` which is a base64 + XDR encoded object and not all sdks have intuitive methods for accessing that), feel free to open another question if you struggle with that.

Comment: Yes that's what I thought as well, but my transaction is failing because of the memo

Comment: It's probably too long or has a wrong type?